# How to remove unneccessary vertices without affecting outer shape?

Tags: mesh

I'm really new to blender and the world of 3d. I've got a model made with solidworks and I have a lot of unneccessary vertices. Is there a way to remove those without affecting the outer shape? There are so many, it's impossible to do this by hand.
[image]

Using the "decimate" modifier I'm not able to improve this shape without loosing quality. especcially those weird connections on the surface become weird shapes. [image]

This is how it should look like. It's a pretty simple shape in this case, should be doable somehow?
[image]

Sorry if  this question is commonly asked but I'm missing terminology here for doing more research.

Comment: what does a X > Limited Dissolve give?

Comment: I don't know, I've found the Limited Dissolve feature but I don't know what information you need. What should I do?

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/